# Numpy way to set all values in a specific dimension of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say I have this matrix in matlab:

```
a(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


a(:,:,2) =

    10    20    30
    40    50    60
    70    80    90
```

Now I can do

```
a(:,:,2) = zeros(3,3)
```

and I get

```
a(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6
     7     8     9


a(:,:,2) =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
```

The only way I could replicate this behaviour ( a(:,:,2) = some array ) in python with numpy is the good old loop

```
for dim0 in range(a.shape[0]):
    for dim1 in range(a.shape[1]):
        a[dim0, dim1, 1] = 0
```

Is there a better numpyish way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep. Exactly the same way as in Matlab. Your loop does the same as:

```
a[:,:,1] = 0
```

You can read more about it [in the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html).